# Apply border to element only when height goes beyond 300px

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have an element which height isn't fixed. Depending on the number of elements inside of it, it can grow and grow, but I have a `max-height: 300px;` to ensure it won't go beyond 300.
What I would really like would be if, when this element gets to 300px, a `solid 2px` border could appear on the bottom of the element (to signal to the user that he can now scroll).

Do you know a CSS solution to do it? If I have to rely on Javascript, how would you do it (I use Angular)?

Comment: have you tried using `media queries`?

Comment: No because to my knowledge `media queries` apply to the full window, not to a single element. I might be wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you have tagged in angularjs. Lets try to make a custom attribute directive for this:

```
directive('maxHeightBorder', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, el, attr){
            if(el.height() >= attr.maxHeightBorder){
                el.css('border-bottom','2px solid');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Then simply use it like this:

```
<div max-height-border="300"> <!-- set your max height here -->
</div>
```

When it reaches 300px in rendered height, a `2px solid border-bottom` will appear

**JSFiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/7auQw/

Comment: it would do what I want, but maybe it's because I'm not too familiar with custom directives, and can't make it work :/ I'll keep trying

Comment: What's the problem? :) Create a new .js file and put the directive in it like this: `angular.module("yourApp").directive('maxHeightBorder')[...]` - then include your js file in index.html and simply use the custom attribute as per my example above.

Comment: I have updated my answer for simplicity. Give me a comment if you still can not make it work, and I'll try my best to help.

Comment: that's exactly what I did ;) I'm not sure why it fails, I feel debugging is still a pain with Angular :/

Comment: My element is an <ul> and not a div, that's the only major difference I see. I don't know how to paste blocks of code in the comment section.

Comment: Im inserting `console.log()` here and there. It seems the `if`fails, even though the element's height is clearly 300px

Comment: Still debugging: `el.height()` returns 0. Imma investigate this `el`

Comment: I think I see the problem. The directive seems to be evaluated only once, when the DOM is created. At this moment, ofc my element is empty (filled with angular ng-repeat afterwards), so height is 0. After loading, it goes above 300 but the directive won't apply.

Comment: How do I make it so that it is constantly being checked for?

Comment: This should be a new question. Please mark this as accepted and create a new question and I will help you out :)

Comment: I'll do just that. Not sure how to phrase this next question though, I know too few of Angular not to make it sound silly ^^

Comment: it's right here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19563159/how-to-make-an-angular-directive-check-constantly-for-an-elements-height