# How to make an angular directive check constantly for an element's height?

Tags: css, angularjs

I use this directive :

```
App  
  .directive('maxHeightBorder', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function($scope, $el, $attr){
            if($el.height() >= $attr.maxHeightBorder){
                $el.css('box-shadow','0 0 5px 5px black');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

With this element : `<ul class="list-group" id="events-list" max-height-border="250">`

Problem is: when I load the page, this element is empty and the directive's `if` statement fails. After loading, Angular fills this element its height goes above 250px, but then the directive won't be checked for, so the new style is never applied.

Comment: How do you fill the element with content? Please show some more code

Comment: `<li class="list-group-item" ng-click="editEvent(trackedEvent)" ng-repeat='trackedEvent in trackedEvents'>` inside the ul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
directive('maxHeightBorder', function($timeout){ // inject $timeout wrapper
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, el, attr){
            $timeout(function(){
                if(el.height() >= attr.maxHeightBorder){
                    el.css('border-bottom','2px solid');
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

See also: [How JavaScript Timers Work](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/)

Comment: A timer would be the fallback solution if everything fails. This is a conditional CSS that might arise often, and I don't want to sink under dozens of concurrent timers. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: Then you can broadcast / emit custom events and check for those. See: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope